# Angular: custom validator isn't firing

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to define a custom validator for a template-driven form. I am providing a Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ng-foo-validator]',
  providers:
      [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => FooValidator), multi: true}]
})
class FooValidator implements Validator {
  validate(c: AbstractControl) {
    debugger;
    return c.value && c.value.fooField === 'foo' ? null : {notFoo: true};
  }
}
```

Then, inside my component, I try to use the `ng-foo-validator` directive:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-model-foo-validator',
  template: `
    <br><br>
    <b>Here's a form with a custom validator!</b>
    <form>
      <input name="fooField" ngModel ng-foo-validator>
    </form>
  `
})
export class NgModelFooValidator {
}
```

However, the `validate` method never fires. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my directive was not declared in `app.module.ts`:

```
declarations: [
  NgModelFooValidator,
  FooValidator,
],
```

A good way to debug this is to make the directive affect some visible property of the element. I put this on the directive constructor:

```
constructor(el: ElementRef) {
  el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

which made it very clear whether or not the directive was being constructed.